# C++ allocator that resets after every "operation"

Tags: c++, allocator

I have a memory allocation need where I will need a bunch of integers for a given "operation".

This "operation" lasts a few microseconds, and almost always I will not need any memory. Let's say 70% of the time.

The remainder of the time, I need one or two, sometimes more. I know for a fact that this number will never be greater than 32768 (2^15).

Should I just allocate 128KB of memory upfront, then keep a pointer to the head. As soon as my operation ends, I reset the pointer to 0.

Is this a cache-friendly allocator?

Comment: *"As soon as my operation ends, I reset the pointer to 0."* - do you mean after all the invocations of your operation have completed, you'll `delete[]` the `int`s?  If so - yes, that's cache friendly.  Repeatedly allocating and deallocation the memory would not be good.  Using some stack memory and falling back on dynamic memory only if it proves insufficient is another option.

Comment: using the same memory is cache-friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate maximum memory you can use at a time to the pointer and try to use the same memory for the whole program. As you said you require a maximum of 2^15 , so initially allocate this amount to the pointer and use the same